# Open API generator allOf not generating model correctly

Tags: java, openapi, maven-plugin, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I want to generate our models based on an Openapi spec 3.0 yml definition. In my spec I have a definition using `allOf` to include the fields of the other components. When generating the models with the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`. I see the following warning `allOf with multiple schemas defined. Using only the first one`.

The result is that only the first `allOf` definition's properties are included. While I expected all fields to be included. https://editor.swagger.io/ generates the schemas correct.

Why are not all properties defined in an `allOf` included?

Schema definition:

```
Dto:
  title: Dto
  type: object
  properties:
    created_by:
      type: string
      format: date-time

Foo:
  title: Foo
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/Dto'
  properties:
    fooProperty:
      type: string

Bar:
  title: Bar
  type: object
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/Foo'
  properties:
    barProperty:
      type: string
```

maven plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>myspec.yml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
                            <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The result is `Bar` with only the fields of `Dto` and `Bar` but not those of `Foo`.
Why are not all properties defined in an `allOf` included?

Comment: Did you find any answer? I am facing same issue..where generating kotlin files, it generates only allOf field, but no other properties are in generated class. Please let me know if you found a solution

Comment: @sgupta https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10010 - no solution yet

Answer (score 5):

The way `allOf` is processed has recently changed, as of v6.5.0, in order to deal with the exact issue you're describing. The changes were motivated by [this issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10010), and introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/15039).

The new functionality is not default behaviour, however. In order to try it, you can use the `REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY` flag. The following example is for the [openapi-generator-cli](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator-cli), though it can easily be extended to the Maven plugin using the [`openApiNormalizer`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin#:%7E:text=follow%20the%20spec.-,openapiNormalizer,-openapi.generator.maven) configuration.

```bash
openapi-generator generate -g <target_language> -i <api_spec_file> -o gen --openapi-normalizer REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY=true
```